# How to create a graph of users in python so that an edge between two users exist if the distance between those 2 users is less than some value?

Tags: python, graph

I want to have an undirected graph

[image]

so that V is the set of all users (represented by their 3D locations) and E is the set of links between the users, with the condition that the link exists only if the distance between the two nodes is within some threshold. I found a library called [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/tutorial/tutorial.html) but didn't find how to add edges based on the distance condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by initializing the graph from an numpy array so that the node distance becomes the weight and then running a loop over the weights to remove the edge if the distance exceeds some threshold `R`.

```
import networkx as nx
import random
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

random.seed(42)

# user locations
def initialize_area():
    x_vals = random.sample(range(1, L-1), I) # I is number of users, L length and B breadth
    y_vals = random.sample(range(1, B-1), I)
    z_vals = [0]*I

    coordinates = list(zip(x_vals,y_vals,z_vals))
    # plt.scatter(*zip(*coordinates))
    plt.scatter(x_vals, y_vals)
    # print(coordinates)
    plt.xlabel("X-axis (m)")
    plt.ylabel("Y-axis (m)")
    plt.title('Simulation Area')
    plt.show()
    print("coordinates = ", coordinates)
    create_graph(coordinates)

def create_graph(coordinates):
    A = np.array(coordinates)
    B = squareform(pdist(A))
    print("B=", B)
    G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(B)
    for i in range(I):
        for j in range(I):
            if G.get_edge_data(i,j) !=None:
                if (G.get_edge_data(i,j)['weight']>R):
                    # print("i=",i, "j=",j)
                    G.remove_edge(i,j)
    analyze_graph(G)


def analyze_graph(G):
    nx.draw(G)
    print("nodes=", G.number_of_nodes(), "edges=", G.number_of_edges())
    plt.show()
    # for i in range(I):
    #     for j in range(I):
    #         print( "i=",i,"j=",j,G.get_edge_data(i,j))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    initialize_area()
```